# Can't make a 301 redirect to home when parameters

Tags: .htaccess

Hi guys I need to redirect all addresses that have the promoG601.aspx in the url to the home page so I created the following rule

RewriteRule promoG601.aspx(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301]

If I send promoG601.aspx it takes me to www.domain.com correctly 
but if I do promoG601.aspx?tid=b then it takes me to www.domain.com/?tid=b

Can you please tell me what am I missing here, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I found that worked was to add a `?` to the end:

```
RewriteRule promoG601.aspx(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L,R=301]
```

Worked for me but I would have thought there would be a better way of doing it.

Just found that the querystring is added by default:

> use the ? to discard the querystring
>   which is otherwise preserved by
>   default